# Call API / Web Request from CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-cloudformation

I wish to call a REST API endpoint at the end of my CloudFormation template.

```
PUT https://example.com/v1/endpoint
{
  // Body Content
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Only way I can think is:

1. Create a lambda function
2. Execute the lambda function with CF
3. Delete the lamdba function

The above approach seems very messy & more effort than necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). It's a resource that is handled by a Lambda function. That function doesn't have to create any actual resource. It can just call that endpoint of yours. If you define the Lambda function as part of your stack, it will be deleted when the stack is deleted.

The Lambda function gets something like the following:

```
{
   "RequestType" : "Create",
   "ResponseURL" : "http://pre-signed-S3-url-for-response",
   "StackId" : "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:123456789012:stack/stack-name/guid",
   "RequestId" : "unique id for this create request",
   "ResourceType" : "Custom::TestResource",
   "LogicalResourceId" : "MyTestResource",
   "ResourceProperties" : {
      "Name" : "Value",
      "List" : [ "1", "2", "3" ]
   }
}
```

And needs to send something like the following back to the URL in `ResponseURL`:

```
{
   "Status" : "SUCCESS",
   "PhysicalResourceId" : "TestResource1",
   "StackId" : "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:123456789012:stack/stack-name/guid",
   "RequestId" : "unique id for this create request",
   "LogicalResourceId" : "MyTestResource",
   "Data" : {
      "OutputName1" : "Value1",
      "OutputName2" : "Value2",
   }
}
```

To make this easier, Lambda functions have access to [cfnresponse](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html#cfn-lambda-function-code-cfnresponsemodule) which implements the response code.

Here's a full example:

```
Resources:
  CustomFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import cfnresponse
          from botocore.vendored import requests
          def handler(event, context):
            if event["RequestType"] in ["Create", "Update"]:
              requests.put("https://example.com/v1/endpoint", {})
            elif event["RequestType"] == "Delete":
              pass  # if you want to do something on delete, do it here
            cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, {}, "ok")
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt CustomFunctionRole.Arn
      Runtime: python3.6
  CustomFunctionRole:
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
  Custom:
    Type: Custom::Something
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt CustomFunction.Arn
```

You should handle exceptions in your code and use `cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.FAILED, {}, "ok")` to make sure CloudFormation doesn't just sit and wait for something. It can take a while to time out.